# Android studio cannot be opened. Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Android studio 2020.3 cannot be opened after  I installed IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3.
When you click the program, there is no response after jumping。

```
Last login: Thu Dec 23 22:31:56 on ttys001
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio ; exit;                 
xxx@xxxMacBook-Air-M1 ~ % /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio ; exit;
2021-12-23 22:51:56.871 studio[1527:28529] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2021-12-23 22:51:56.873 studio[1527:28532] Cannot load JVM bundle: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3585 "dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try installing a universal version of the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “OpenJDK 11.0.10” couldn’t be loaded because it doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture.}
2021-12-23 22:51:56.873 studio[1527:28532] Retrying as x86_64...
arch: posix_spawnp: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio: Bad CPU type in executable
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[进程已完成]
```

Local JDK

```
xxx@xxxMacBook-Air-M1 ~ % /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.291.10 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_202 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Users/jagtu/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you try to run Intel verion on M1 mac. You need to choose a **.dmg (Apple Silicon)** option when downloading Android Studio.

Comment: the Android Studio could have started before.  it's not the problem